# css rollover bug

Tags: css

Ok this one is driving me mad !

its bound to be something simple, but i cannot find it.

http://keith464.fahrradhamburg.de

When you rollover the nav, you get a white background and blue font.
But when you go down to one of the dropdowns, the background stays white (as it should)
but the font reverts to white, instead of staying blue ?

Can some css guru, please give me a clue, as to whats going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

```
.kw-class > li > a:hover { color: blue }
```

do

```
.kw-class > li:hover > a { color: blue }
```

Comment: yep !
brilliant - wish i could give more points :-)
- been driving me mad